# How to setup rails 3 with apache on windows 7

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, ruby-on-rails

Does anyone have a good tutorial on how to configure Rails 3 with apache on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Rais 3 is more of an "experimental" release right now. This [tutorial should still work though](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=34). Unless you need to know how to install Apache as well?

There's also InstantRails (http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl?Getting_Started) which includes Apache and everything else for you in a very simple package. I hope one of those two things is what you are looking for.